# How to decrease the memory consumption of a WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, memory

The test site requires a lot of memory when viewing some category/archive pages.

I met with the following error messages yesterday:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 48 bytes) in
>   /var/www/t/wp-includes/load.php on
>   line 552
>
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 209715200 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 40 bytes) in
>   /var/www/t/wp-includes/meta.php on
>   line 307

The problem was solved by adding the "define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '210M');" line to the wp-config.php file.

But this is not good enough. The production site will have much more data than the test site, which means I have to add the "define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '2100M');" line to the wp-config.php file. And 2100M may not be large enough as the time goes by.

How to decrease the memory consumption of the WordPress site dramatically? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's a ludicrous amount of memory to be consuming per request. Perhaps you might have better luck posting this on the Wordpress forums as they will be more familiar with the internals of Wordpress.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

It turns out that the high memory consumption is caused by a file in the current theme.

Comment: What file in the WordPress theme requires that amount of memory? And/or what is that file trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Tim The archive file tries to load all the coordinates before showing them in the Google Maps. There is a big LOOP.

Comment: I'd say there's probably a better way then to load all of the coordinates. We built a site on WordPress using Google Maps and integrating tweets with them without loading all of the coordinates on first load. We loaded a sample at the 10k' overview level and then as the user zoomed in, we'd show more detailed information. Maybe you can utilize this same functionality by setting some limitation on it, like the most current map entries or if there's multiple entries in a city, only show one of them for that city. Is any of that possible?

Comment: @Tim Thank you very much. I'm trying to combine AJAX with the Google Maps, and with the WordPress. It'd be great if you could explain your experience in detail in your blog. BTW, your beach house is very nice. :)

Comment: @boxoft - I'll see what I can do. I'm not sure how much of it I can go into detail w/o revealing who we white labeled for. But if I'm not able to, try to find a way to sample your data at each level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory consumption can be reduced by many things. Instead of posting everything here, I'll just point out some good resources.

- http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Optimization/
- http://storecrowd.com/blog/wordpress-optimisation/
- http://www.earnersblog.com/digproof-your-wordpress/
- http://beerpla.net/2009/06/09/how-to-make-your-site-lightning-fast-by-compressing-deflategzip-your-html-javascript-css-xml-etc-in-apache/

[Also check out this Plugin to monitor your memory usage.](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-memory-usage/)